# Restart game for Rock, Paper, Scissors

Tags: python, python-3.x

Beginner Coder creating a rock paper scissors game. Trying to get used to using OOP in my coding and I can't get the game to restart. I've looked on the internet to improve my coding and I think I'm making this worst. Help Please!!! Here's my code:

```
import random
import sys


class User:
    # ask user for name
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = User_name


class Results:
    # record user input
    while True:
        def __init__(self):
            user_input = input("Pick rock, paper, or scissors?")

            self.selection = user_input

        def output(self):
            #return cpu output and run through the game

            cpu_output = random.choice(("rock", "paper", "scissors"))

            if self.selection == cpu_output:
                print(f" {User_name} it looks like we're tied")
            elif self.selection == "rock":
                if cpu_output == "paper":
                    print(f"Paper beats rock. {User_name} it looks like I won this round")
                else:
                    print(f"Great job {User_name}. Rock beats scissors it looks like you won this round")
            elif self.selection == "paper":
                if cpu_output == "scissors":
                    print(f"Scissors beats paper. {User_name} it looks like I won this round")
                else:
                    print(f"Great job {User_name}. Paper beats rock it looks like you won this round")
            elif self.selection == "scissors":
                if cpu_output == "rock":
                    print(f"Rock beats scissors. {User_name} it looks like I won this round")
                else:
                    print(f"Great job {User_name}. Scissors beats paper it looks like you won this round")



        def restart(self):
            #allow user to restart the game

            game_reset = input("Would you like to play again?")
            if game_reset == "Yes" or "yes":
                print(f"Starting up a new game {User_name}")
                rps_game.output()
            else:
                print(f"Exiting the game. Thanks for playing {User_name}")
                sys.exit()
        break




User_name = input("What is your name? ")
```

Comment: What did you found after doing research about your problem? Please mention those things also in question. Try to give your idea like think we have do thing to solve kind of things.

Comment: What is `rps_game`?

Comment: rockpaperscissorsgame

Comment: @Kshitiz initially I was seeing a lot of people stating, to implement a while loop in my class to make the program run and potentially restart and then breaking the loop.

Comment: Can you point where you found that? Looping inside class, strange...

Comment: @paradocslover this was the article I used https://www.python-course.eu/python3_loops.php. Looking at it now it was not used inside a specific class.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, your code does require a lot of changes. But here I am providing with you something to start with:

```
import random
import sys


class User:
    # ask user for name
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = User_name


class Results:
    # record user input
    def __init__(self):
        user_input = input("Pick rock, paper, or scissors?")

        self.selection = user_input

    def output(self):
        #return cpu output and run through the game

        cpu_output = random.choice(("rock", "paper", "scissors"))

        if self.selection == cpu_output:
            print(f" {User_name} it looks like we're tied")
        elif self.selection == "rock":
            if cpu_output == "paper":
                print(f"Paper beats rock. {User_name} it looks like I won this round")
            else:
                print(f"Great job {User_name}. Rock beats scissors it looks like you won this round")
        elif self.selection == "paper":
            if cpu_output == "scissors":
                print(f"Scissors beats paper. {User_name} it looks like I won this round")
            else:
                print(f"Great job {User_name}. Paper beats rock it looks like you won this round")
        elif self.selection == "scissors":
            if cpu_output == "rock":
                print(f"Rock beats scissors. {User_name} it looks like I won this round")
            else:
                print(f"Great job {User_name}. Scissors beats paper it looks like you won this round")



    def restart(self):
        #allow user to restart the game

        game_reset = input("Would you like to play again?")
        if game_reset == "Yes" or "yes":
            print(f"Starting up a new game {User_name}")
            self.output()
        else:
            print(f"Exiting the game. Thanks for playing {User_name}")
            sys.exit()




User_name = input("What is your name? ")
while True:
    result = Results()
    result.output()
    result.restart()
```

You do not `define` the function to use them, you `call` them.

Other than that, there are a few more issues. Like for example, the game never stops. Where to look into to debug that? `if game_reset == "Yes" or "yes":` Are you sure this is the correct way to check the connection? Or do you think you missed out something.
Is that it? Check and try to figure out.

SO is a community to ask doubts, pinpointed doubts. Not questions like - "My code's not working, fix it!" But anyways you have something here.

Comment: Agreed....thanks for the clarification I'll look into that area of my coding and see if Google can help me fix it. Thanks for the direction. I usually only post on here when I've actually tried the coding and I'm running into a roadblock.

Comment: For now, maybe you can consider upvoting and accepting. If you run into any more errors from here, you can edit your question here and comment on this answer saying that you have made a change. I will get a notification that way and I will help you!!

Comment: Np I upvoted I'll try to revise it and let you know of any progress I make. Thanks

Comment: Accept it as well, for now, may be.

Comment: can you elaborate more on your previous statement "You do not define the function to use them, you call them". More specifically can you show me an instance in which I did this so I can learn it.

Comment: define a function = ```def func(): //do something``` whereas calling a function = ```func()``` . So, when you have to use them (inside the `while` loop) you call the function like I have done.